Can I use the `use` hook in a context to get data from a promise
Situation
I have a UserContext that handle the auth of my app.
Here is how it looks like
const UserProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const login = async (userName: string, password: string) => {
    try {
      const { user } = await authlogin(userName, password);
      setUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      // error handled by api-client
    }
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setUser(null);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser()
      .then(({ user }) => setUser(user))
      .catch(() => setUser(null))
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, []);

  const isAuthenticated = user !== null;

  return (
    <UserContext value={{ isLoading, user, isAuthenticated, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext>
  );
};

Somewhere else in my app I have a RequireAuth component that checks for the current user, if any:
const RequireAuth = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const { isLoading, isAuthenticated } = useUserContext();

  if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
  }

  return children;
};

Question
I want to take advantage of the latest use hook and Suspense of react 19 but I cannot manage to make it work in this situation. Is it even a use case for the use hook? If not, how should I make my UserContext to work with Suspense?
If I do something like const { user } = use(getUser()); inside my context, then it run in an infinite loop.
As you can see the login also need to set the user.

Can you share the code where you try to use use() ?

I want to replace the useEffect where I fetch getUser  by use(getUser)

You need to pass the Promise returned from getUser() to the child component:
Acoording react 19 webiste: use does not support promises created in render.

"To fix, you need to pass a promise from a suspense powered library or
framework that supports caching for promises. In the future we plan to
ship features to make it easier to cache promises in render."

For example:
const UserProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const login = async (userName: string, password: string) => {
    try {
      const { user } = await authlogin(userName, password);
      setUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      // error handled by api-client
    }
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setUser(null);
  };
  const response = getUser()

  const isAuthenticated = user !== null;

  return (
    <UserContext value={{ response, isLoading, user, isAuthenticated, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext>
  );
};

And inside your UserContext :
const UserContext = ({value}:{value:AuthProps})=>{
     ...//other stuffs  
     const {response} = value;
     data = use(response)
     return (
        <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p<}>
          <ErrorBoundary errorComponent={yourErrorComponent}> 
          {data}
          </ErrorBoundary> 
        </Suspense>);
}

Then, until the Promise for getUser() is completed, the fallback component from Suspense is shown.
I hope this helps !!
